Bôcher's theorem for singularities on the boundary
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be connected, open, bounded, and  smooth. Suppose that $u\in C^0(\bar \Omega\setminus \{0\})\cap C^2(\Omega\setminus\{0\})$ is harmonic and positive in $\Omega$.
If $0\in \Omega$, Bôcher's theorem tells us that $u(x)=v(x)+a \log |x|$ where $a\leq 0$ and $v\in C^0(\bar \Omega)\cap C^2(\Omega)$ is harmonic.
I'm wondering if a similar statement is true in the case where $0\in \partial \Omega$, let's say under the additional assumption that $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega\setminus \{0\}$.
I found some references for $p$-harmonic functions (e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-006-0003-7) where crude asymptotic estimates for $u(x)$ as $x\to 0$ are obtained. Is there a classic reference for harmonic functions? I feel that this should be more accessible and and that the results should be stronger.
Thanks!
